# Elasticsearch query for this particular type of typo: "bath mat" vs "bathmat"

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to get results from Elasticsearch when someone enters the incorrect word, "bathmat" -- the correct spelling is "bath mat". In other words, when someone enters the incorrect word, "bathmat" I want to Elasticsearch to return results as if the correct words, "bath mat" were entered.

Here's my query:

```
GET localhost:9200/products/_search
{ 
    "size": 10000,
    "query": { 
        "bool": {
            "minimum_should_match": 1,
            "should": [
                {
                    "match": {
                        "title": {
                            "query": "bathmat",
                            "fuzziness": "AUTO"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match_phrase": {
                        "main_description": "bathmat"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "must": [
                {
                    "nested": {
                        "path": "taxonomies",
                        "query": {
                            "bool": {
                                "should": [
                                    { "match": { "taxonomies.name": "bathmat" }}
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone either A point to the relevant Elasticsearch documentation / blog posts or explain below how I can create an Elasticsearch request which will get me the results I am looking for?

Comment: are you interested specifically in extra/missing whitespace or any typo with `fuzziness:1`?

Comment: @BohdanStupak I tried `fuzziness:1` instead of `fuzziness: "AUTO"`, and I am not noticing any difference.

Comment: you have a couple of branches searching for bathmat and only one of them uses fuzziness